# token pushwoosh is nil

Tags: objective-c, pushwoosh

in my app a pushNotificationManager give me a pushToken equal nil... only with IOS 8.1.3.... device is ipad3. With other device (or with other IOS version) my test it's ok..

i used this code to call getPushToken...

```
[[PushNotificationManager pushManager] getPushToken]
```

and in my appDelegate I have

```
-(void) settingPushwoosh:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // set custom delegate for push handling, in our case - view controller
    PushNotificationManager * pushManager = [PushNotificationManager pushManager];
    pushManager.delegate = self;

    // handling push on app start
    [[PushNotificationManager pushManager] handlePushReceived:launchOptions];

    // make sure we count app open in Pushwoosh stats
    [[PushNotificationManager pushManager] sendAppOpen];

    // register for push notifications!
    [[PushNotificationManager pushManager] registerForPushNotifications];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you receive delegate callback when push token received? Sometimes you need to wait a little as this is asynchronous operation.

Comment: Yes I recieve delegate callback. The pushNotificationManager object isn't null, but all its properties are nil....